# Migrar web wordpress site a local

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theme, wamp

El ex-webmaster dejó un backup de nuestro site caido, dicha web creada en wordpress.

Intento probar el backup en LOCAL (Apache 2.4.8, MySQL5.7, PHP 5.6) mientras me reestablecen el servidor (al cual se migrará la web)

Leí un tutoríal en el que copiaba los archivos a la dirección local 
(http://localhost/tepsur)
Y modificaba la base de datos del backup, cambiando la dirección http://www.XXXX.com por http://localhost/XXXX, en mi caso me dí cuenta de que la base de datos hacía referencia a http://XXXX.com (sin www)

El esquema de la BD es el natural de Wordpress compuesto por: wp_commentmeta wp_comments wp_links wp_options wp_postmeta wp_posts wp_term_relationships wp_term_taxonomy wp_terms wp_usermeta wp_users.

Bueno, realicé el cambio y restauré la base de datos configurando el acceso a base de datos en wp-config.php

Sin embargo no me sale un error en concreto... me sale lo siguiente:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es un ejemplo del juego de caracteres que me aparece:

> :�X�����|A�==h�}����$M4��ER���"�Y�� �������:A�i$�����Zy���]��O��,ۧr*ڡj���L�)g ◵���Y�ER����r�O�h�Z�e�%�%�4.    ��e}�=��k�@�����x�� ��[�Q?��0� M%�c�n�2�,4�b����c4�{�G(��)�}1/��ɮ֡��]�8+�B�t�.C�Ȝ���҆���uvx‌​�c|�K�9J���ދH�����}Ǘ‌​,�wz��:�l�߰njڎh����%‌​�vЮ[I�Ts,-q�m<�N���_‌​k����m�\��U3�$�P$#�?‌​Z�)�5�#�X?�5k1 ���i��-����Ţ�w:��� �J� i5ut#��J��B�O#��{0��]Y3LQ�s�>C��r:B��iD����<�,x�yf�D'aF�we��‌​�LuANAJS�Y�>C��xE�`�‌​��ݐS�4�pp�^�U�[�[��r‌​2�\��~ˋ��"����˜�����‌​� �����Fw �z�^f�0&��zV�pN0ʝ�M�#z��

Por favor agradezco por anticipado su colaboración que ilumine mi camino.

Comment: copia y pega el error textualmente por favor.
creaste el esquema de la BDD? ya creaste los usuarios? tienes la base de datos del wordpress?

Comment: Buenas noches, agradeciendo por anticipado tu ayuda.

En el foro no me deja adjuntar mas de 600 caracteres; y el error tiene como 20000 caracteres; no veo un error en concreto, solo código CSS como texto y carácteres sin aparente sentido.

El esquema de la BD es el natural de Wordpress compuesto por:
wp_commentmeta
wp_comments
wp_links
wp_options
wp_postmeta
wp_posts
wp_term_relationships
wp_term_taxonomy
wp_terms
wp_usermeta
wp_users
Incluso antes de tratar de cambiar en el script de la base de datos la url www tepsur com por localhost/tepsur aparecían los mismos errores CSS.